# need to handle double and single quote in C# code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to handle both double and single quote in my code behind , but none of them are working. Below is my code

```
private String _systemPath;

public String SystemPath
{
    get {

       // return _systemPath = _systemPath.Replace("'", "\'").Replace("\"", @"\\\""); 
       return  _systemPath = _systemPath.Replace("'", @"\'").Replace(@"\""", "\"");

    }
    set { _systemPath = value; }
}
```

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please add a few examples of what you are trying to achieve. e.g. `'c:\somepath'` should become `"c:\somepath"`.

Comment: "Not working" is not an error. What do you expect to happen and what happens? Take a look at the [String.Replace() manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx).

Comment: This doesn't look like it would compile. There are mismatched quote characters in your strings (aka @"\""" has 1 too many quote characters in it). What is "not working?"

Comment: @Tejs No, it doesn't.  It's a literal quote so the end result will be `\"`, `""` is an escape sequence for one double quote.

Comment: @Servy \" is the escape for ", but there is no escape character for \"" like above. The first non escaped " terminates the string, so there is literally another string ", " right after.

Comment: @Tejs No, that would be true in a regular string but the preceding `@` makes it a literal string, so `\\` ceases to be an escape character.  Put it into a compiler and print it to the screen to see for yourself.

Comment: I am getting an unterminated string literal error with the @ sign. I am trying to put a backslash where ever there are double quotes. I succssfully put backslash for single quotes, but for double quotes, I was not able to do it.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to add a `\` before each single or double quote then you're indeed close:

```
_systemPath.Replace("'", @"\'").Replace("\"", @"\""");
```

What you have is the reverse; you're changing all escaped double quotes to non-escaped double quotes.

Comment: well, I am passing this system path value to a javascript function and whereever there are double quotes, the function stops working, I succssflly handled the single quotes, but with the above answer, I am still not able to invoke the javascript function.

Comment: @AvinashChandra Well, that depends on context, it's hard to say without knowing how you're using it.  It's possible you're escaping strings that shouldn't be escaping, for example.

Comment: in tis particuar link, I am passing a value 3" clothing material pointer's

Comment: @AvinashChandra That's still lacking in the required context.

Comment: so how can I make 3" clickable.

Comment: @AvinashChandra What you need to figure out is, given the string that you have, what do you need to turn it into.  This code will turn it into: `3\" clothing material pointer\'s` and that may or may not be what you want given how you're using it.  I would start out hard coding the resulting string until you figure out what your end result needs to be, and *then* focus on how to turn what you have into that format.

Comment: I have been struggling with this for more than an hour. does not work.

Comment: @AvinashChandra And saying "does not work" doesn't help anyone.  You need to provide more information about what you're doing if you want anyone to help you, nobody has enough information to help.  You've said what string you're passing in, but not what you need to be passing out, and how that differs from what this passes out.